# DropDownMenu using MVCSiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I am using asp.net mvc3 razor engine and trying to use the MVCSiteMap provider for rendering the menu, but when i am using the multi-level Site-map, menu control render all the node over the page without and Hover functionality.

Please tell, there is any way to this.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't worded very well, but basically he's asking for navigation menu functionality.  I'm looking for the same thing myself.  Basically, the MVC sitmap provider default template just seems to show all the nodes all at once, regardless if it's a child node or not.  What he's looking for (and myself as well) is for only the TOP level nodes to be shown (which you can do easily enough), but for the CHILD level nodes to be visible when you hover over the parent links.  Basically, the way the old asp:Menu used to work in ASP.Net with the original sitemapprovider.

I'm sure this is just a templating issue, but I'd be shocked if no one else has already done this.  Not having much luck finding it though.

Comment: Thanks Phil, you are right that was just only template(CSS) issue.